# OK and Cancel in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to implement a classic OK and Cancel concept in a bootstrap modal.

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      user can select an option here from a list
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the model content, there is a  and the user can select one of the options. If OK is clicked, I would like to handle the new option. If not, no action is required. For that I hook on the hide.bs.modal event, but that is called when Cancel is clicked.

How can I differentiate between Cancel and OK buttons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, Bootstrap does not support specific modal events for the modal actions buttons. So, I believe you will have to handle the events yourself like so.

```
    $("#myModal").on("click",".btn-default", function(){
       // code
    });

    $("#myModal").on("click",".btn-primary", function(){
       // code
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add an click event to OK button? If you do not add `e.preventDefault()` to your event you can process normally.

First add your OK button a definitive ID or class name:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      user can select an option here from a list
      <select name="select" id="select1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <button type="button" id="btn_ok_1" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add a click event to that button:

```
$("#btn_ok_1").click(function (e) {
  var selectedOption = $('select#select1 option:selected').val;

  // Do some work with selected item.
})
```

Comment: And how do it (add event) in my js file (bootstrap 5.2) ? And then how to close after doing some works (in end of click event function);